# Как дать роль участнику сервера временно discord.py (python)?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, discord-api

У меня есть бот, у которого есть команда  `!emprison`. Данная команда должна добавить роль участнику сервера, но на время которое было задано. Как добавлять роли я знаю, но как дать **временно**? Также мне нужно чтобы команда работала только если у участника который написал команду, есть определенные роли.

Пример кода:

```
import discord
from discord.ext commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def emprison(ctx, member_mention, time):
    time = int(time)

     user = ctx.author
     guild = self.get_guild(id)
     role = guild.get_role(id)

     await user.add_roles(role) # И тут выдается роль, но навсегда. Как это сделать временно?
```

Comment: Временно — это насколько? Если несколько минут или часов, то можно задержку выставить (`await asyncio.sleep(time_in_seconds)`), если в днях или месяцах, то тут уже лучше сохранять в файл дату, когда роль нужно забрать, а затем при запуске бота читать этот файл и проверять у каких участников нужно забрать роль именно сегодня.

Comment: Для теста временно я могу взять 10 секунд. И для этого использую `asyncio.sleep(10)`. Но как через время удалить роль у участника?

Comment: Вы же где-то в документации нашли метод для выдачи роли `add_roles`. Там же должно быть написано про метод, чтобы забрать роль. Скорее всего `remove_roles` или как-то так

Comment: Ну не в документации, а на этом сайте, когда искал как добавить роль. Но как ее забрать я не нашел (и причем через время). Вопрос уже решен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример команды для выдачи роли и затем удаления её.

```
@bot.command()
async def emprison(ctx, member: discord.Member, duration: int):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Имя_роли')  
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send("Такой роли нет.")
        return

    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Роль {role.name} добавлена пользователю {member.mention} на {duration} секунд.")

    await asyncio.sleep(duration)

    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Роль {role.name} удалена у пользователя {member.mention}.")
```

Пример команды:
!emprison @mrBars1k 10

Думаю, проблем с адаптацией под Ваши нужны не возникнет.

Comment: Если останутся вопросы, то задавайте их в комментарии здесь. Если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку решения, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое